# Testing with two servers launched

Tags: python, flask

My project has 2 apps: `api` (for handling API endpoints) and `api-content` (for handling file uploads), each listening on a different port. Does anyone know how i can run my test cases with both servers launched? E.g., file uploads need authentication on the api server. my test cases derive from `TestCase` and have `create_app` implemented, but that seems to be designed for testing with only one app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two apps, one for each port:

```
apiapp.config['TESTING'] = True
apitest = apiapp.test_client()

apicontentapp.config['TESTING'] = True
contenttest = apicontentapp.test_client()
```

and use these two test clients to access either app. There is no need to actually *run a server*.

Note that this would go well beyond unit testing, you are in the realm of integration or even functional testing here.

Comment: I've tried something similar and run `app1.run(host=...)` in `create_app` but `create_app` doesn't return (I think it's trying wait for `app1.run(..)` to return. Is there a way to spin `app2` off as a separate process/thread?

Comment: Why run it at all? Just use the test client; you don't need actual networking here, unless your views expect to contact the other server via HTTP (in which case I'd mock that interaction instead).

Comment: Ah! Interesting. I'll do that then. Thanks.